# Are non-Christians buried in Christian cemeteries?

Tags: non-christians, burial, custom

A prominent Christian cemetery in New Delhi has a grave containing the mortal remains of a former President of India, a Hindu by profession. His wife was a practicing Christian; kept some ashes after the cremation of her husband as per Hindu custom, and wished that they be buried alongside her own grave after her death. Hence the combined grave.

One is curious to know if there are such instances of multi-religion burials in Christian cemeteries elsewhere in the world.

**P.S.**: In metropolitan cities of India, Christian cemeteries are run by committees constituted for the purpose, and are open to members of all denominations. However, in places where Christians are many in number, the local churches maintain denomination-specific cemeteries.

Comment: Church of England graveyards are open to all who die in the parish, or resided there at the time of death. There is no religious discrimination.